# Copy a ListView and show it on a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to copy a ListView from one class to another and show that ListView on a new aspx page. What I am doing is I am selecting certain values from the first ListView and only those items will be shown on a new page. However, I can't figure out how to show the ListView on a new page because I am used to using a SqlDataSource. I am passing the ListView through the addList method and I have already created a new ListView in the new aspx file. 
Please let me know the best way to handle this and if I need to add more information.

Code in First Class

```
public void CloneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String droplist = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        list = new ListView();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(droplist))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "error", "alert('Please select a Program Name and Report Period');", true);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ListView1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                Button1_Click(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {

                var selectAllCheckBox = (CheckBox)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("CheckBox2");
                if (selectAllCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    list = ListView1;
                    Response.Redirect("~/CloneReport.aspx");
                    return;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");

                    if (chk.Checked == true)
                    {
                        list.Items.Add(ListView1.Items[i]);
                    }

                }
                CloneReport rep = new CloneReport();
                rep.addList(list);
                Response.Redirect("~/CloneReport.aspx");
            }

        }

    }
```

Code in Second Class

```
public void addList(ListView list)
{
    ListView1 = new ListView();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListView1.Items.Add(list.Items[i]);
    }
    ListView1.DataBind();

}
```

ListView Item Template From Old Page(Page Im transferring from)

```
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF; color: #333333;">
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="FormTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FormTitle") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="FormSectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FormSection") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="SubSectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubSection") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="SectionItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionItem") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="SortOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SortOrder") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="SectionSortOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionSortOrder") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="SubSectionSortOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubSectionSortOrder") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="RuleDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RuleDesc") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="ControlType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ControlType") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="CrossItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CrossItem") %>' />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Triggers for Update Panel

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CloneButton" />

        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:Button ID="CloneButton" runat="server" Text="Clone Report Period" OnClick="CloneButton_Click" />
            </div>
            <div  style="text-align: center; position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0">
                <b>Program Name</b>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Program" DataValueField="ProgramID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp &nbsp
                <b>Report Period</b>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="ReportLabel" DataValueField="DataCollectionPeriodID" Height="21px" Width="172px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="30px" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transfer ListView object between pages, but you can do it with DataTable using Server.Transfer.

**First Page:**

```
DataTable dtTable;
public DataTable DataTransferTable
{

   get { return dtTable; }
}


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstTransferView = new ListView();

    DataView dtView = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    dtTable = new DataTable();
    dtTable = dtView.ToTable().Clone();
    DataRow dtRow;
    foreach (ListViewDataItem lstItem in lstView.Items)
    {
         if (((CheckBox)lstItem.FindControl("chkBox")).Checked)
         {               
             dtRow = (DataRow)dtView.Table.Rows[lstItem.DataItemIndex];                                        
             dtTable.ImportRow(dtRow);
         }
    }

    Server.Transfer("~/SecondPage.aspx");
}
```

**Second Page:**

```
public FirstPageClass ftPage;    
DataTable dtNewTable;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
           ftPage= (FirstPageClass)Context.Handler;

     dtNewTable = (DataTable)ftPage.DataTransferTable;

     lstSecondView.DataSource = dtNewTable;
     lstSecondView.DataBind();              
}
```

Comment: Hmm one problem at dtRow = (DataRow)dtTable.Rows[lstItem.DataItemIndex]; If I am constantly removing rows when DataItemIndex gets past the half way mark it doesn't see any more rows there. IndexOutofBounds

Comment: What exactly is PagingSample.UpdatePanel this is the only part my program is stuck on now. I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Updated the code for 1st page. "PagingSample.UpdatePanel" is a class of my sample project. Please replace it with class of your first page.

Comment: This is the error I get after the DataBind. Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Ive been trying to look up the error, one site recommended ScriptManager scriptManger = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            scriptManger.RegisterPostBackControl(this.ListView1); But thats not working.

Comment: Submit button should not be under the update panel when Server.Transfer() is used on the button click. Please put CloneButton out of the UpdatePanel. Or use PostBackTrigger for CloneButton.

Comment: If it helps I am using an update panel with asyncpostback triggers on my old listview(which I need so the page doesnt refresh when I make changes)

Comment: It worked thanks so much! Saved me again. I will give you all the points that I can! I changed clonebutton to postbacktrigger.